# Cannot dismissViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing a strange problem -

I have a navigation Controller(`NV`) which presents the Root Controller(`NVV1`). `NVV1` pushes another view controller on top of it called `NVV2`.

`NVV2` presents a modal controller (`MV1`). `MV1` presents another modal controller (`MV2`).

On a user action in MV2, it dismisses itself by calling `self.presentingViewController dimissViewControllerAnimated`. After dismiss, `MV2` calls a method of `MV1`. That method in `MV1` does a network call and now (*tries to*) dismiss itself by calling `self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated` to show `NVV2` and calls a method of `NVV2` as well.

The problem I am facing `MV1` is not getting dismissed. Am I missing something? The error that I am getting -

```
attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = <MV1: 0xaebbfc0> modalViewController = <UINavigationController: 0x1976ac10>
```

Comment: Are you trying to immediately go from MV2 to MV1 to NVV2 without pausing?

Comment: Not that that's not doable… Just asking because if that's the case, I may have an idea as to the problem with your code.

Comment: Yes... The user takes a action on MV2 which then shows the screen MV1 where a network operation takes place. After the network operation is over, it moves to NVV2. Yes, all without pausing for any user action moving from MV2 to MV1 to NVV2.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on the `presentingViewController` instead of `self`. Normally, this would be fine, but if you look at the [Discussion section for `dismissViewControllerAnimated`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated%3acompletion%3a) a presented view controller will automatically forward to it's presenting view controller.

In this case, you may have found a minor bug where multiple presented view controllers don't check if they are also a presenting view controller before forwarding the message. If you change the calls to `self`, you might be able to prevent `MV1` from forwarding the message to `NVV2`.

Comment: That doesn't work. I changed to `self` in both MV1 and MV2 to dismiss them. `MV2` does get dismissed but `MV1` still doesn't. The error - Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <MV1: 0xb95ac00> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're attempting to dismiss the MV1 view before MV2 has been dismissed.  Either try adding a slight delay before dismissing MV2:

```
[self performSelector: @selector(dismissMV1) withObject:nil afterDelay: 0.1f];
```

**Or better yet**, you could try calling the `dismissMV1` method *from* the MV2 method by using a completion block (available in iOS 5.0 and above) to trigger `dismissMV1` once the dismissal is complete:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
     [self.presentingViewController dismissMV1];
}];
```

Comment: Oh, I think I initially misread your comment underneath my comments on your initial post…  So you're saying that MV1 is actually showing up on your screen after you dismiss MV2?  In which case I may be wrong with my above theory...

Comment: And from the change in the warning you received upon making the change hukir suggested, it's also possible that the best solution involves a combo of both of our answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by directly calling `dismissViewController` on `NVV2`, that is in `MV2`, I called `[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissControllerAnimated]`.

That solved my problem in this case as I wanted to move from `MV2` to `NVV2` directly. Ideally, I would have liked to move to `MV1`, do some network operation and indicate the user that a network operation is ongoing on `MV1`, but in my case showing that on `NVV2` also works fine.

The original question, though, still remains unanswered - how to move from `MV2` to `MV1` and then to `NVV2` directly. I think this might be a minor bug because according to the docs, if you call `dimissControllerAnimated` on a view it sends the message to its parent as well - essentially, the call going all the way to `NVV2` which is undesirable. I do not yet have a solution for this.

Comment: I am not marking this as the right answer because it does not solve the initial question - this just solved my use case.